# reuse and combine SVG path d strings in animate values

Tags: svg, svg-animate

I'm animating a path through several d values and am constantly reusing the same shape. In the simplified example below I'm morphing a main triangle `M 1,5 L 9,1 9,9 Z` into 3 smaller triangles. To do this, I've had to write the d value for the main triangle into the `<animate/>`'s values attribute 4 times.

```html
<svg width="100" height="100" viewBox="0 0 10 10" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink">
  <path fill="black" stroke="none">
    <animate attributeName="d" values="M 1,5 L 9,1 9,9 Z;
                                       M 2,2 L 5,8 8,2 Z;
                                       M 1,5 L 9,1 9,9 Z;
                                       M 7,3 L 3,3 5,7 Z;
                                       M 1,5 L 9,1 9,9 Z;
                                       M 6,4 L 6,6 4,5 Z;
                                       M 1,5 L 9,1 9,9 Z" dur="3s" repeatCount="indefinite" />
  </path>
</svg>
```

With more complicated animations and shapes the SVG gets large, error-prone, and generally difficult to work with. Ideally I could do something like: `<animate values="${a};${b};${a};${c};${a};${d};${a}" ... />`. Is there a way to do this without javascript?

I thought I got close with CSS variables and a data URI as the content property of ::before ...but data URIs aren't strings (and what I really want isn't a hack but a "right way" that I missed)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In SVG2, the `d` attribute has become a presentational attribute and can therefore be set by CSS.
We can thus use it in css animations, with css-variables.

But the browser support is still very low (only Blink as of today).

```html
<svg width="100" height="100" viewBox="0 0 10 10" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink">
  <style>
:root {
  --def-A: path("M 1,5 L 9,1 9,9 Z");
  --def-B: path("M 2,2 L 5,8 8,2 Z");
  --def-C: path("M 7,3 L 3,3 5,7 Z");
  --def-D: path("M 6,4 L 6,6 4,5 Z");
}
path {
  animation: path-change 3s linear infinite;
}
@keyframes path-change {
  0%   { d: var(--def-A); }
  17%  { d: var(--def-B); }
  33%  { d: var(--def-A); }
  50%  { d: var(--def-C); }
  66%  { d: var(--def-A); }
  83%  { d: var(--def-D); }
  100% { d: var(--def-A); }
}
  </style>
  <path fill="black" stroke="none"></path>
</svg>
```

So given it's just a one time thing, you can also just consider using the `replace-all` method of your text-editor to make the edition easy.

Comment: this is exactly what I was hoping for when I asked this question. I'd searched for a couple of hours for the ability to do it just as you described... but struck out. thank you! It's for an in-browser editor and Chrome only is just fine for now.

Comment: how do you know this? I've searched for combinations of 'svg2', 'path', 'presentational attribute', etc and have found very little documentation explaining your code/syntax (which doesn't really need explanation as it's clean and working but...). If possible, I'd like to know if this is a feature from the future or an unsupported (but elegant) chrome bug that could disappear any moment. The closest I've found is a passing reference in some SVG meeting minutes from 2016 :) Thanks again!

Comment: The truth is "by answering questions here" ;-) I often have to go to the spec drafts  like svg2 where  [presentation attributes](https://svgwg.org/svg2-draft/styling.html#PresentationAttributes) are extended by what is still a "Candidate Recommendation" (so it could change in the future, but given main browsers have already caught up with other attributes, no reason `d` won't be implemented in a near future everywhere). For the remaining, that's stable CSS syntax, except the `path()` function which also is part of a [still-draft spec](https://drafts.csswg.org/css-shapes/#basic-shape-functions)